# How to export more than top 10k results from Lens.org?

Tags: databases

I've been using Lens.org from quite sometime now and I am stuck on the exporting part. I can't add more than "top 10k results" in a collection and hence can't export more than that. The number of patents in my search query is well, above 50k.

Is there any alternative from where I can get data in similar format?

To clear up any confusion, Lens.org is a free patent database. I'm not sure if this is the right community to ask this question.

Comment: I suppose you could break up your query with date ranges and merge after exporting.

Comment: Have you tried asking the lens support or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to The Lens' support [pages](https://www.lens.org/support/help-resources/workspaces/export-collections-and-results/):

> The lens supports exporting of metadata for up to 1000 search results
>   or 10,000 collection items. You can access the export function via its
>   icon on the result listing header or from the “Collections” tab of the
>   Work Area. When exporting from the result listing header, the export
>   function takes into account any filtering or sorting you may have
>   done, giving you the ability to finely tune the documents you wish to
>   export.

You might try to break up your collection by date ranges and then merge after exporting. There may be other sites that are better suited to your needs.

Comment: This actually worked. The only problem was confirming the date of last patents in collection and then filtering my search query. A little extra effort but it works. Thanks!